# Cordova Office 365 Calendar Client App with Ionic works on Android but not IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ms-office, office365api

I am developing a hybrid mobile application with Cordova and the Ionic Framework.
I have been using Visual Studios 2015 and have added the Office 365 APIs extension and configured it with an O365 Developer account. I added code similar to whats found [here](http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/1795) .

As a Developer using Windows, it is not easy to test on IOS with out a MAC. I only got one last week and got it configured with xcode, ionic etc.

So, My app is working on Android - Device, Emulator and Ripple environment.
In the Calendar section of the app I can view outlook calendar events, delete them and add new ones and this all works pretty well.

Yesterday I ran the same app on IOS emulator and IOS device (iPhone 6s running latest IOS) and the majority of the app works pretty well except adding calendar events! It displays Outlook events, lets me delete them but will not add new ones (throws no errors, just sits there). I am unable to debug the problem as xcode will not display any errors and the Ionic CLI will not show either.

Has any one had any similar problems with O365 API and IOS device?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Let me know if more detail is needed, quite new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simulator might not have an accessible calendar. Try to connect Xcode to an actual IOS device.